# Difference between Htaccess and Mysqli methods preventing SQL injections

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mysqli, sql-injection

I want to secure my WordPress blog from SQL injections.

I have many PHP custom pages with queries to the database and to custom non-wordpress tables.

**I know I can use 2 methods:**

1) MySQLi or PDO for prepared statements and parameterized queries.

2) htaccess rules like the following:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} [a-zA-Z0-9_]=http:// [OR]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} [a-zA-Z0-9_]=(\.\.//?)+ [OR]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} [a-zA-Z0-9_]=/([a-z0-9_.]//?)+ [NC,OR]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \=PHP[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12} [NC,OR]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\.\./|\.\.) [OR]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ftp\: [NC,OR]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} http\: [NC,OR]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} https\: [NC,OR]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \=\|w\| [NC,OR]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)/self/(.*)$ [NC,OR]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)cPath=http://(.*)$ [NC,OR]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\<|%3C).*script.*(\>|%3E) [NC,OR]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\<|%3C).*iframe.*(\>|%3E) [NC,OR]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^i]*i)+frame.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode.*\(.*\) [NC,OR]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_(en|de)code[^(]*\([^)]*\) [NC,OR]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(\[|\]|\(|\)|<|>).* [NC,OR]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (NULL|OUTFILE|LOAD_FILE) [OR]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\./|\../|\.../)+(motd|etc|bin) [NC,OR]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (localhost|loopback|127\.0\.0\.1) [NC,OR]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|>|'|%0A|%0D|%27|%3C|%3E|%00) [NC,OR]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} concat[^\(]*\( [NC,OR]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} union([^s]*s)+elect [NC,OR]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} union([^a]*a)+ll([^s]*s)+elect [NC,OR]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (;|<|>|'|"|\)|%0A|%0D|%22|%27|%3C|%3E|%00).*(/\*|union|select|insert|drop|delete|update|cast|create|char|convert|alter|declare|order|script|set|md5|benchmark|encode) [NC,OR]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (sp_executesql) [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F,L]
```

Using htaccess method would be extremely easy and fast. Are there downsides using this?

Comment: This is definitely implementation specific.

Comment: Use prepared statements. It's easier and it works for any type of data. ($POST, $GET, etc)

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton seeing that someone upvoted your comment, `$POST/$GET` should really show what the real [superglobals](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) are `$_POST/$_GET` as some may think (even the OP) that `$POST, $GET` are correct syntax. The comment should be edited. Edit: and it can't be edited now. Please use proper syntax, it's more helpful that way and clearer for everyone.

Comment: I can see this type of implementation restricting wanted data instead of preventing SQL injection.

Comment: @Fred-ii- you're right, my bad

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton It happens. Well.. you know and I know and other seasoned coders know/knew what you meant by that :) yet the OP and future readers may not. I just wanted to clarify things for everyone.

Comment: You htaccess might prevent certain queries that could be used for sql injections, but it is impossible to tell if it would be successful in all situations. For prepared statements you on the other hand will know that the used variables are definitely escaped.

Answer (score 0):

As i see, you are blacklisting things you think it's harmful. I wouldn't trust that because there may be something you could forget or other breach that could be open in the future and you will not remember to add it to the file.

A better aproach is whitelist what you know it's ok, but i don't know if it's possible in the htaccess.

I think the ideal aproach is what it was suggested in the comments. Use the prepared statements for PDO or `mysqli_real_escape_string()` and/or `settype()` for mysqli extension.

Answer (score 0):

Using  **Prepared Statement**  is best solution  to Prevent a website From **SQL injection** because  as you are saying
you can use **htacess**  property but it is not the best way to secure your website  from sql injection. 
**htacess** only help to secure from URL  based injection but by using **Prepared  Statement** it will help you to prevent  from all type of sql injection

After  doing  this

you can also test your website security or vulnerability using [pentesterking.com](https://www.pentesterking.com)

Answer (score 0):

You htaccess might prevent certain queries that could be used for sql injections, but it is impossible to tell if it would be successful in all situations - and it most likely wont.

For prepared statements you on the other hand will know that the used variables are definitely escaped.

The htaccess rules might even prevent valid input, e.g. if you have a application that maintains SQL code, and you want to allow the user to search for queries, then it might be perfectly valid to for a query to contain strings that you filter in your htaccess.

Using htaccess rules for this purpose are hard to maintain, error prone, and the worst of all, if you look at your code you can never be sure if the variables you pass to the queries are not harmful. You will always need to examine all possible ways  to the point where the variable is used and check if it is modified on that way in anyway that could result in anything malicious.

The idea of prepared statements and any other validation methods is, to do them as close to the point where you use them as possible. Thats the only way how you can keep your code maintainable, because you only need to look at a small portion of the code to check if it is vaild.